# How to sort an array contains complex strings with fractions in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, fractions

I have the following values in an array,

```
$values = array(
            "1/4x1/4x1", 
            "1/2x1/2x1", 
            "3/4x3/4x1", 
            "1/4x1/4x2", 
            "1/2x1/2x2", 
            "3/4x3/4x2", 
            "1x1x1", 
            "1x2x1", 
            "2x1x1"
        );
```

Considering the numbers in between 'x', I want the ascending order of the values as the following,

```
$values = array(
            "1/4x1/4x1", 
            "1/4x1/4x2", 
            "1/2x1/2x1", 
            "1/2x1/2x2", 
            "3/4x3/4x1", 
            "3/4x3/4x2", 
            "1x1x1", 
            "1x2x1",
            "2x1x1"
        );
```

I'm new to PHP. Are there any specific functions for this? If not, please help with a way to find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't be the last two elements the other way around? Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo The first part of the number should be the smallest

Comment: on which part basis you want asscending? `1/` or `4x1/` or `4x1`(last)

Comment: @AlivetoDie Priority is from left, the first section before x, then the section between 2 xs, last the section after the 2nd x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit complex, but you can avoid using [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

```
// Transpose resulting 2x2 matrix using array_map behavior of
// tacking an arbitrary number of arrays and zipping elements, when null
// giving as a callback.
$evaluated = array_map(null, ...array_map(function ($factors) {
    return array_map(function ($factor) {
        // Explode fraction (into array with two elements)
        // and destruct it into variables.
        // `@` will silent the notice if not a fraction given (array with one
        // element).
        @list($dividend, $divisor) = explode('/', $factor); // **

        // If divisor is given then calculate a fraction.
        return $divisor
            ? floatval($dividend) / floatval($divisor)
            : floatval($dividend);
    }, explode('x', $factors));
}, $values));

// Assign values array by reference as a last element.
$evaluated[] =& $values;

// Unpack all arrays (three columns of fractions and given array) and pass
// them to `array_multisort` function, that will sort in turns by each of
// the columns.
array_multisort(...$evaluated);

print_r($values);
```

So, basically, we map each item from the array into an array of calculated fractions and then transpose this array to end up with three arrays representing columns. Then we pass this three array along with given array into [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), that takes the given array by reference and reorders it as we want.

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b18abb9eed857c70e872f0599526287eb074fed3).

Comment: OP says they are new to PHP. While this answer works, even I with 17 years experience in PHP had troubles understanding it at first. Would you mind explaining it? Also, you should mention that this will only work in PHP 7.1

Comment: @masterfloda, sorry, my bad. I have changed `@[]` to `@list()`, so it works on PHP >= 5.6.

Comment: @sevavietl Thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me how should I modify the code if my array has string keys. ie.`$values = array("name" => car, size => '1/4x1/4x1', "name" => van, size => '1/2x1/2x1')`

Comment: @Niroshan, it should work as it is if your array looks like this: `array('car' => '1/4x1/4x1', 'van' => '1/2x1/2x1')`. In the docs of `array_multisort` stated that "Associative (string) keys will be maintained, but numeric keys will be re-indexed."

Comment: @sevavietl When I tried it i get the following error
`Cannot unpack array with string keys`. When i referred the doc for `array_map` it's stated that string keys cannot be used. Please help me with a solution
[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/74f2453b1f9879f80d94c2c679bb26c8ebb3d929)

Comment: @Niroshan, yes I see. when you prepare columns for sorting, you don't need keys, so you can replace `}, $values));` with `}, array_values($values)));` Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ebe952dfbc3bf16cb8de728d2fe1ed7d30254ce).

Comment: @sevavietl Thank you for your demo. As I mentioned earlier I'm new to php. This is how my array looks like. I want to sort the array according to the size as you have given in the answer. 
`$values = [];
$values[] = array('name' => 'item1', 'size' => '1/4x1/4x1');
$values[] = array('name' => 'item2', 'size' => '1/4x1/4x2');
$values[] = array('name' => 'item3', 'size' => '1/4x1/4x3');`
Hope you can provide me a solution

Comment: You can use `array_column` to extract only `'size'` column. Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/745daff4d6a7906faf9b3e7a40e033ae67451167).

Comment: @sevavietl `array_column` works perfectly. Now the issue is with the array values. Values also contain mixed fractions. Example: `$values = []; $values[] = array('name' => 'item1', 'size' => '1 1/4x1/4x1'); $values[] = array('name' => 'item2', 'size' => '1 1/2x1/4x2'); $values[] = array('name' => 'item3', 'size' => '2 1/2x1/4x3');` Is there a way to sort this as well?

Comment: @Niroshan, well, this is not how SO works. You have to do some programming yourself actually. But to bring to a logical end, here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4fa47368b7465e1944422cff6486f67e0485a54). As this parsing a little more complex than simply exploding the string, regex is used.

Comment: @sevavietl I actually did the coding and found a solution with simple explode function. For [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dbff0c0c87b95a9be7f56c498ddfcc687f6b703a). But your code looks much cleaner. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `eval()`! It is evil. And you can avoid it easily. You need to create a callback method for [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) that compares the dimensions (and if necessary converts fractions to numeric values).

I assume you always have 3 dimensions and they are either a positive integer or a fraction. I also assume that you are not sorting by volume but by dimension 1, dimension 2, dimension 3.

```
/**
 * usort callback to sort dimensions
 * @param {string} $a first comparable value
 * @param {string} $b second comparable value
 * @returns {int} 0, 1 or -1
 */
function sortByDimension($a, $b) {
    $dimA = getNumericDimensions($a);
    $dimB = getNumericDimensions($b);

    // first dimension is the same: compare deeper
    if ($dimA[0] == $dimB[0]) {
        // second dimension is the same too: compare deeper
        if ($dimA[1] == $dimB[1]) {
            if ($dimA[2] == $dimB[2]) {
                // value is the same: return 0
                return 0;
            }
            // value A is larger: return 1, value B is larger: return -1
            return ($dimA[2] > $dimB[2]) ? 1 : -1;
        }           
        return ($dimA[1] > $dimB[1]) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return ($dimA[0] > $dimB[0]) ? 1 : -1;
}

/**
 * converts a string value to an array of numeric values
 * @param {string} $val string of dimensions AxBxC
 * @returns {array} an array with 3 dimensions and numeric values
 */
function getNumericDimensions($val) {
    // split the value into the 3 dimensions
    $dimensions = explode('x', $val);

    // loop through the values and make them numeric
    // note: the loop is per reference: we override the values!
    foreach ($dimensions as &$dim) {        
        // check if it is a fraction
        if (strpos($dim, '/') !== false) {
            // split the fraction by the /
            $fraction = explode('/', $dim);
            // calculate a numeric value
            $dim = $fraction[0] / $fraction[1];
        } else {
            // make it an integer
            $dim = (int)$dim;
        }
    }
    return $dimensions;
}

$values = array(
        "1/4x1/4x1", 
        "1/2x1/2x1", 
        "3/4x3/4x1", 
        "1/4x1/4x2", 
        "1/2x1/2x2", 
        "3/4x3/4x2", 
        "1x1x1", 
        "1x2x1", 
        "2x1x1",
    );

// sort the array (note: usort is per reference)
usort($values, 'sortByDimension');
print_r($values);
```